# IcCube - accessing Report Code with Javascript

Tags: iccube

When I am editing a report, I can click on "Report Code" to see information about the report structure. It loks like this:

```
{
"classID": "ic3.ReportGuts",
"guts_": {
    "ic3Version": 12,
    "schemaName": "test_schema",
    "cubeName": "Cube",
    "layout": {
        "classID": "ic3.FixedLayout",
        "guts_": {
            "ic3Version": 12,
            "grid": 10,
            "boxes": [
                {
                    "classID": "ic3.FixedLayoutBox",
                    "guts_": {
                        "ic3Version":...
```

How can I access this Information  with Javascript? context.$report apparently doesn't give this information.

Also is there a way to get the information, what MDX statements are used in the different charts of a report? And can this be altered with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get report guts add this code to the **Report Code**:

```
function consumeEvent( context, event ) {                                
  if (event.name == 'ic3-report-init') {                                 
    console.log(event.value.state.report);
  }                                                                      
}
```

As for handling mdx request before send, it's kinda harder. Again in **ReportCode**:

```
function consumeEvent( context, event ) {                                
   if (event.name == 'ic3-report-init') {       
    event.value.widgetMgr().forEach(function(idx,item){
        if(item.hasOwnProperty('onVizBeforeRequestSend')){
            return;
        }

        var oldMethod = item.onVizBeforeRequestSend.bind(item);
        item.onVizBeforeRequestSend = function(request){
            console.log(item, request);
            oldMethod(request);
        }
    });
}
```

In this function item is widgetAdapter with info about the widget and request is request instance.

Comment: 1. The Javascript tells me, that event.value is undefined. if I console.log(event), I get only Object{type:null,name:"ic3-report-init",value:undefined}
2. Where do you get your knowledge from. Is there some Text I can read to learn more about stuff like this?

Comment: @UlrichWuenstel What version of reporting you are using?

Comment: Works for me at 5.2 (2997):
http://demo3.iccube.com/icCube/doc/tutorial/ic3report-tutorial.html?ic3demo

Click "Edit report" at the bottom of a page and than try the first code block.

Comment: Yes you are right, there it works. Now I need to find out, why it doesn't work in our setup ^^

Comment: I set up a new instance of IcCube and got everything working. That's a gamechanger :)