# IcCube - Global function accessing report guts

Tags: javascript, iccube-reporting

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526926/iccube-accessing-report-code-with-javascript/38529460?noredirect=1#comment64521394_38529460) we learned, how to get to the guts of an icCube report from the reports javascript (via the "event" object), whereas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000857/iccube-javascript-function-applied-to-all-reports/39015942?noredirect=1#comment65495371_39015942) it is shown, how to bind a function on every report rendered.

Is there a way, to combine both? So can you bind a function on every report rendered, which lets you receive the guts of said report?

The "event" object doesn't exist there and in the "viz" object or in "this" I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use reporting variable, it alllows to get access to the opened report:

```
var originalStart = ic3.startReport;
ic3.startReport = function(options) {
    var reporting = originalStart(options);
    reporting.bind(viz.EventType.onReportRendered, 
                   function(){
                       alert("Report guts: " + reporting.context_.mainReport().state.report)
                   });
    return reporting;
}
```